# Custom events for GlassFish in Java Flight Recorder / Java Mission Control

Tags: java, glassfish, glassfish-4, glassfish-4.1, java-mission-control

I've read that GlassFish provides custom events for Java Flight Recorder (JFR) / Java Mission Control (JMC).

I tried viewing in JMC 5.4 a JFR 5.3 recording obtained from GlassFish 4.1 running in Java 7u67.  The recording was setup from the command line using `jcmd`.  I did not use JMX or MBeans.

I saw the standard JFR events, but no custom events for GlassFish.

Are there actually custom JFR events for GlassFish?  If so, what are they, how do I record them, and how do I view them?

Thanks.

Here's an article that mentions GlassFish JFR events:

http://www.infoq.com/news/2013/10/misson-control-flight-recorder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I’ve understood things correctly, this was something that the GlassFish team wanted to address in the commercial version of GlassFish. Then it was decided to not do a commercial version of GlassFish.

Note that there are JFR events for the WebLogic Server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Is there any documentation or example code of custom events so that I can try to make some for GlassFish myself?

Comment: Thanks again for the additional info.  Your blog post mentioned that the API might change: has it changed in any significant way since your post?  Or will it be changed anytime soon?  (e.g., in Java SE 8u40)

Comment: Nope. It has not changed, and will not likely change until JDK 9.